# Como localizar e selecionar option com label específico de select com jQuery

Tags: jquery, formulário

Com jQuery, como altero o label de um option, e não o value, exemplo:

```
<select id="meuSelect">
    <option>[nao_selecionar_esse label]</option>
    <option>[SELECIONAR_esse label]</option>
    <option>[nao_selecionar_esse label]</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Você teria mais options dentro do select? Qual evento dispararia essa alteração? Tente ser mais especifico sobre o que precisa fazer na pergunta

Comment: Teria sim, tentei dessa forma 
var tipofaturaPagtos = "[ALTERAR_ESSE_LABEL]"

$("#tipofaturaPagtos").val(tipofaturaPagtos).change();

Mas ele verifica o value, e não o label.

Comment: Poste tudo como você tentou, trabalhar com jquery e options é complicado por isso, ainda mais se tiver mais options e precisar pegar um valor especifico pra marcar, senão poderia ter respondido que pode usar o text() no lugar do val()...

Answer (score 1):

Use `text`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('select option:nth-child(2)').text('alterado').attr('selected', 'true');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="meuSelect">
        <option value='10'>[ALTERAR_ESSE_LABEL]</option>
        <option value='10'>[ALTERAR_ESSE_LABEL]</option>
        <option value='10'>[ALTERAR_ESSE_LABEL]</option>
    </select>
```

Obs: esse `nth-child` no seletor é para pegar o primeiro `select`, não afetando os outros caso venha a ter mais de um.

Comment: Agora que notei um erro, o código altera o label, queria localizar o label igual ao valor passado no .text(); e marcá-lo como selected ( .change(); )

Comment: editei a pergunta com o que você quer

Comment: Mas ele não deve ser necessariamente o option 2, pois a lista tem 15 options, e ao cadastrar o usuário seleciona um, e ao editar, ele deve selecionar o option com a label que está no banco, poderia ser por value que é simples, mas é uma Procedure do cliente que não pode ser alterada.

Comment: Perdão não entendi nada, seja mais objetivo, o que quer fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$("select").find("option").html("SEU_TEXTO");
```

Ou se caso você queira este específico **option** pode fazer assim

```
$("select").find("option[value=10]").html("SEU_TEXTO");
```

Comment: Essa opção funcionou para mim, adaptei. $("#tipofaturaPagtos").find("option").html(tipofaturaPagtos).change();

Comment: Agora que notei um erro, o código altera o label, queria localizar o label igual ao valor passado no .text(); e marcá-lo como selected ( .change(); )

Comment: no caso você pode fazer assim `$("select").find("option[value=10]").attr("selected","true")`